# Ansible Shell/Command Module - "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory",

Tags: ansible

I would like to run Command "ll /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-* " to get the scsi ID. I've tried command and Shell with become: yes, but no luck.

```
- name: Get ISCSI Id
  command: ll /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-*
  register: iscsiid
  become: yes
```

Error:

```
    "changed": false,
    "cmd": "ll '/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-*'",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "ll /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-*",
            "_uses_shell": false,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory",
    "rc": 2
}
```

Any Idea how to run this command? It works whenI run manually as root user.

Thanks,

Comment: this isnt a problem with ansible or its moduels, the problem is the command itself "ll /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-*"..., try running it with just "ll /dev/disk/*"

Comment: I'd bet $1 it's because `ll` is a bash alias for `/bin/ls -l`, and furthermore you cannot use `command` with shell globs like that, as [the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/command_module.html#command-module) very clearly states

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use the shell module instead of command, also replace the ll alias with a shell command like 'ls' - i tried and it works :

```
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - shell: ls -lstr /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-*
    register: iscsiid
    become: yes
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ iscsiid }}"
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working after changing the command from ll to ls -ltr. really appreciate your help.

Comment: if you are satisfied, please accept the answer. thanks